# POST error searching API

Tags: javascript, php, forms, api, post

I'm experimenting a little with the OMDb API. I am managing to search for a film, but not with spaces. As soon as I use a space in my search it returns null.

> Examples:
>
> Search: Hot Return: {movieName: "Hot Fuzz"}
>
> Search: Fuzz Return: {movieName: "Fuzz"}
>
> Search: Hot Fuzz Return: {movieName: "No results"}
>
> Search: Poet's Return: {movieName: "Poet's Pub"}
>
> Search: Poet's Pu Return: {movieName: "No results"}

I'm presuming that space as a special character isn't correctly formatted, and thus the default return string appears. I can't figure out how to solve it though. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

HTML/JS:

```
<form id="fetchFilm" method="post">
    <input id="searchString" type="text" name="searchString">
</form>

<br>

<p id="mTitle"></p>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('form').each(function(e) {
            $(this).find('input').keypress(function(e) {
                // Enter pressed?
                if(e.which == 10 || e.which == 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    findFilm();
                }
            });
        });
    });

    function findFilm() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "movieFinder.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#searchString'), //Here is where I presume the problem may be.
            success: function(data){    
                var movieTitle = data.movieName;
                document.getElementById("mTitle").innerHTML = movieTitle;
            },  
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST)) {

    function curl_get_contents($url) {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }

    $searchString = $_POST['searchString'];

    $url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=MyKey&t=".$searchString;
    $movie_json = json_decode(curl_get_contents($url), true);

    $movie['movieName'] = $movie_json['Title'];

    if(!empty($movie['movieName'])) {
        //Do nothing
    } else {
        $movie['movieName'] = "No results";
    }

    echo
        json_encode(array(
            'movieName' => $movie['movieName']
        ))
    ;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the result you are getting, try URL encoding the search string when applying it as a query parameter:

This will work:
https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=&t=Hot%20Fuzz

Comment: Thank you. I guess I did think that was the answer (but didn't know to search for "URL encoding"), but apparently needed a wildcard * added to the search query aswell

Answer (score 1):

`$('#searchString')` gives you the jquery-wrapped element, not the input's value. Try this instead:

`data: $('#searchString').val()`